# send Files automatically to a new folder via Batch

Tags: batch-file

I found this BatchCode which uses the first word from files to create a folder and send all files with the same word in the new Folder. What should the code look like if it uses the WORDS in Brackets without the Brackets to create the new Folders?

This is the Codefragment - Thank your for your help.

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('dir "%srcdir%" /b /-p /a:-d /o:gne') do (
    if not exist "%destdir%\%%i" md "%destdir%\%%i"
    move "%srcdir%\%%i %%j" "%destdir%\%%i"
    echo "%destdir%\%%i\%%j"
    echo.
```

Comment: Your code is missing a closing parentheses. You description seems pretty simple. `"%destdir%\[%%i]"`

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Your Code adds a second Bracket to the first. So the Folder now Calls ((Hello)
I need it that way: The Wordfile names (Hello how are you)thatsversion1.docx 
The Batchfile should create a Folder thats named by the Words in Brackets without Brackets - example: Hello how are you
Sorry for the bad explanation at first.